# How to add ngx-restangular to angular-seed?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-seed

I have a skeleton application build with `mgechev/angular-seed` and `2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular`. I would like to integrate them but I cannot find out the solution how to do it.

Before I successfully add few packages to `project.config.ts` simply following `angular-seed` documentation.

Here is a piece of configuration that works fine:

```
...
  # tools/config/project.config.ts 

  let additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[];
  additionalPackages = [ {
      name: 'angular2-jwt',
      path: 'node_modules/angular2-jwt',
      packageMeta: {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
      }
  }, {
      name: 'ngx-progressbar',
      path: 'node_modules/ngx-progressbar/bundles/ngx-progressbar.umd.js',
  }, {
      name: 'ng2-charts',
      path: 'node_modules/ng2-charts/bundles/ng2-charts.umd.min.js'
  }, {
      name:'ngx-bootstrap',
      path:'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.min.js'
  }, {
      name:'ngx-bootstrap/*',
      path:'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.min.js'
  }, {
      name:'ng2-select-compat',
      path:'node_modules/ng2-select-compat/bundles/ng2-select-compat.umd.min.js'
  }, {
      name:'ngx-avatar',
      path:'node_modules/ngx-avatar/ngx-avatar.umd.js'
  }];
...
```

But when I'm trying to add `ngx-restangular`:

```
...
# tools/config/project.config.ts 

const additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
    {
        name: 'ngx-restangular',
        path: 'node_modules/ngx-restangular/dist/esm/src/',
        packageMeta: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: './index.js',
        }
    }];
...
```

Application throws an error:

`(index):60 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at eval (<anonymous>)`

In the browser network tab I can see that `ngx-restangular` files are loading:

- index.js
- ngx-restangular.module.js
- ngx-restangular.js
- ngx-restangular-http.js
- ngx-restangular.config.js
- ngx-restangular-config.factory.js
- ngx-restangular-helper.js

[Link](https://github.com/tulik/angular-seed-restangular) to Github repository. **To run it in your local env, please simply clone/fork and `npm install && npm start`**

[Link](https://github.com/tulik/angular-seed-restangular/blob/master/tools/config/project.config.ts#L46) configuration file `project.config.ts`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your index.js?

Comment: @AlfMoh  `node_modules/ngx-restangular/dist/esm/src//index.js` 
https://gist.github.com/tulik/a916e0774d343a0c5592b09bf7c613b4

Comment: Is ngx-restangular in the same .umd.js bundle as the rest?

Comment: Did my answer help in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at this:

[Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297952/error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

It seems its trying to parse a html 404 response. Its quite possible its trying to access a file that it cannot locate. I see you are using .umd.js. Is this correctly configured within your config file? Something like this:

```
additionalPackages.forEach(function (pkgName) {
 packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'bundle/'+ pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
```

The link i passed in here maybe of some help also. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `umd.min.js` file for ngx-restangular. Solution with path `node_modules/ngx-restangular/dist/esm/src/` is loading `ngx-restangular` files.  In compiled JS file https://gist.github.com/tulik/9d1e4ea5201e48abfbd8d1c5e861f193 it can't find `var rxjs_1 = require("rxjs");` which seems to be defined in `angular-seed` here: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/tools/config/seed.config.ts#L609